# Pandas create multiple columns if not exist in different datasets (the datasets are values of a dictionary)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, recursion

I have the following problem;
I have a dictionary which contains a dataset in each value (image attached)[as you will see 57796 and 34733 are the keys and the values are the datasets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k1aL.png)

So each dataset has different columns, but sharing most of them 7 `columns needed_cols = ["osmid", "geometry", "highway", "element_type", "oneway", "surface", "maxspeed"]`

Therefore, what I want to do is to iterate over each dataset and keep these 7 columns for each (just these 7 columns) and create them for the datasets which don't have 1, 2, 3 or none of these columns.

I thought a recursive fn would be a good opt, so I created the following one, and it works, but just for the 1st value, it doesn't work for the rest.

```
def setCols(dic, arr):
for k in dic.keys():
    for col in arr:
        if col not in list(dic[k].columns):
            dic[k][col] = "null"
            return setCols(dic, arr)
        else:
            dic[k] = dic[k][arr]
            return dic
```

Being "dic" the entire dictionay and "arr" the "needed_cols"
As far as I understand, this recursive fn should check if each value of "needed_cols" is in each dataset, if it is not, create it with "null" values and start the fn again until the dataset has all the "neede_cols", or, on the other site, if the dataset has already all the "needed_cols" return the dictionary with each dataset having just the "needed_cols"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.. It was an identation problem and actually with *while* has more sense:

```
def setCols(dic, arr):
    for k in dic.keys():
        for col in arr:
            while col not in list(dic[k].columns):
                print("column doesn't exist")
                dic[k][col] = "null"
                print("column created")
        
        dic[k] = dic[k][arr]
        print("it is ok")
        
    return dic
```